# Properties of a Sturm-Liouville problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to show the following problem is regular.

To show a Sturm-Liovulle problem is regular we need to demonstrate that $y''+\frac{b}{a}y'+\frac{1}{a}(c+\lambda)=0$ where $p(x)=e^{\int \frac{b}{a}\,dx}.$  We then have $[p(x)y']'+[q(x)+r(x)\lambda]y=0.$  Now this is regular if (i) $p,p',r,q$ are all real valued continuous on a finite interval $[a,b]$; (ii) $p(x)>0$ and $r(x)>0$ on $[a,b].$

Consider $x^2y''+xy'+\lambda y=0$ where $x>0$, $y(0)=y(e)=1$, and $y'(0)-2y'(e)=2.$

Dividing through by $x^2$ we get $y''+\frac{1}{x}y'+\frac{\lambda}{x^2}y=0.$  If we let $p(x)=x$  we then have $xy''+y'+\frac{\lambda}{x}y=0.$  This yields us $[xy']'+\frac{\lambda}{x}=0.$  If we let $p(x)=x$, $q(x)=0$. and $r(x)=1/x$, does this show that this problem is regular? Am I missing a step?

Comment: What you did isn't wrong, but I don't think you can force the boundary conditions to sum up to $0$. I worked it out and found that your system doesn't even have a solution. It is an Cauchy-Euler equation. None of the cases is satisfied, the distinct root case is the hardest to see, but you will find that your boundary condition will force it to be the trivial solution, a contradiction.

Comment: Would the cases be satisfied $x>1$?

Comment: if $x > 1$, how do you define the initial conditions then? The main problem is that both $y(0) = y(e) = 1$ here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to show the following problem is regular.

Well, the difficulty is that this is *not* a regular Sturm-Liouville problem, at least not as stated. There is also an issue with the boundary conditions, but we will discuss that in a bit.

Writing the original problem in its Sturm-Liouville form,
$$
{1\over w(x)}\left[p(x){dy\over dx}\right]'+q(x)y+\lambda y(x)=0,\quad a<x<b,\tag{1}
$$
we see $p(x)=x$, $q(x)=0$, $w(x)={1\over x}$. Since the boundary conditions are specified at $x=0$ and $x=e$, the interval here is $0<x<e$. For this problem to be regular, we need $p,q,w,p'$ continuous on $[0,e]$, and $w(x)={1\over x}$ fails this condition. So the problem is not regular.

However, the spirit of the problem can still be salvaged: **singular** Sturm-Liouville problems aim to relax the hypotheses on the functions $p,q,w$ and/or the interval $[a,b]$ while preserving the important qualitative properties of the solution to the problem. Here's a relevant formulation of this notion applicable to your problem:

(1) is **singular** if $p,q,w,p'$ are continuous on $a<x<b$, but $p$, $q$, or $w$ becomes infinite at an endpoint.

Since the interval is $0<x<e$, and $w(x)={1\over x}\to\infty$ as $x\to 0^+$, this is a *singular* S-L problem.

So either you need to appeal to this notion of singular S-L problems or you need to study the problem on an interval away from zero.

Finally, the boundary conditions stated don't make sense since they are specifying three conditions for a second order problem. Maybe you want just $y(0)=y(e)=1$ without the other condition? In such a case, the boundary condition at the singular endpoint is usually replaced by a boundedness condition there, such as 
$$
y(x),y'(x)\text{ bounded as }x\to 0^+.
$$

For the full details of this discussion, a book like Zettl's *Sturm-Liouville Theory* is appropriate.